# Cannot get password in custom LoginModule

Tags: java, security, ejb, jaas, wildfly

I'm trying to write my own LoginModule named `CustomLoginModule` for Wildfly 8.0.0.CR1 which is registered for a security-domain in the `standalone.xml`:

```
<security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">  
  <authentication>  
    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">  
      <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>  
    <login-module>  
    <login-module code="com.someExample.CustomLoginModule" flag="required">  
      <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>  
    </login-module>  
  </authentication>  
</security-domain>
```

In my remote client I'm using the following jboss-ejb-client.properties:

```
endpoint.name=client-endpoint  
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false  
remote.connections=default  
remote.connection.default.host=[...]  
remote.connection.default.port=[...]  
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false  
remote.connection.default.username=myUserName  
remote.connection.default.password=abcde
```

Obtaining the InitialContext in the client looks like:

```
Properties props = new Properties();  
props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,  "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");  
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
```

Basically this works fine and my login-module is invoked when accessing an EJB via the remote-interface which is annotated with the correct `@SecurityDomain`.

In the login-module, I can read the username using the callback or the `sharedState` which is passed to the `initialize` method. But I was not able to get the provided password (in this example I would expect to get shomewhere the string `abcde`).

I have already tried several things to get the password. Via the callback (like I did on JBoss 5), via the given sharedState, ... Even if I derive from the `org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule` or when using code from the JBoss-Quickstart examples, I cannot see the password which has been set at the client. Instead, I always get the following string returned as password `org.jboss.as.security.remoting.RemotingConnectionCredential@...`.

Edit: This is the code of my `LoginModule` (or at least one version of it):

```
import javax.security.auth.callback.*;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule;

public class CustomLoginModule implements LoginModule
{
    private CallbackHandler callbackHandler;

    public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler,
      Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options)
    {
        this.callbackHandler = callbackHandler;
    }

    public boolean login() throws LoginException
    {
        NameCallback namecallback = new NameCallback("Username");
        PasswordCallback passwordcallback = new PasswordCallback("Password", false);
        CallbackHandler handler = this.callbackHandler;
        try {
            handler.handle(new Callback[] { namecallback, passwordcallback });
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String username = namecallback.getName();
        char[] password2 = passwordcallback.getPassword();
        String password = new String(password2);
        System.out.println(username + " / " + password);
        if (username == null || password == null) {
            return false;
        }
        // do authentication...
        return true;
    }

    public boolean commit() throws LoginException
    { ... }

    public boolean abort() throws LoginException
    { ... }

    public boolean logout() throws LoginException
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: is callbackHandler passed to your module a custom one? is `PasswordCallback.getPassword` called at all?

Comment: The callbackHandler which is passed to the `initialize` method is `javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$SecureCallbackHandler`. I'm not aware that I have changed anything in this area - so the passwordHandler should be the "standard"-one.

I'm creating a `new PasswordCallback("Password", false)` and getting the char-array mentioned above (`org.jboss...`) when calling `getPassword` on the callback`.

Comment: I was not very precise in my origin question: if I'm using the password-callback, I get the string as described above. But if I also register the `RemotingLoginModule` in `standalone.xml`, I'll find an instance of `RemotingConnectionCredential` using the `sharedState`-key `javax.security.auth.login.password`. But the problem remains: I don't see a possibility to get the password even if I have access to `RemotingConnectionCredential`.

Comment: `javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback.getPassword` returns a `char[]` not a `String` nor `RemotingConnectionCredential`, maybe you are using a different `PasswordCallback`? will you post the module code?

Comment: I've edited the original post and added the code of the module. Thanks for your support!

Comment: can't see anything strange in your code (nevertheless you shouldn't return false on `login()`, instead throw a `LoginException`, cause false has a "skip" meaning). this seems to be a bug of CallbackHandler/RemotingConnectionCredential implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the hint concerning the returnvalue of the `login`-method. I'll try to start from a "clean" Wildfly-installation using the quickstarts from JDF to find out what is the difference.

Comment: What does your realm definition currently look like for the initial authentication on establishing the connection?

Comment: @DarranL I guess you are talking about the configuration of the xmlns `urn:jboss:domain:remoting:2.0`, do you? Here I have the default settings `<http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>`.
If the `ApplicationRealm` points to the `other` security-domain for authentication using `jaas name="other"`, I get an `LoginException` since the custom login-module cannot be found (though it is deployed).

Answer (score -1):

I've created a small testproject now to find out how I can get this to work. And I think it is worth sharing.

We loop through the `ClientLoginModule` (which is provided by Wildfly)
in the first stage (of the `ApplicationRealm` which is used to secure the remote-
connection). This module stores the credentials (somewhere?) and they are available afterwards to my other login-module.

```
<security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
    <authentication>
        <jaas name="AppRealmLoopThrough"/>
    </authentication>
</security-realm>
```

Of course, this security-domain has to be defined afterwards:

```
<security-domain name="AppRealmLoopThrough" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Client" flag="required">
            <module-option name="multi-threaded" value="true"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
<security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="com.someExample.CustomLoginModule" flag="required"/>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

In the `CustomLoginModule` (which extends `UsernamePasswordLoginModule`) I can do the following to retrieve username and password:

```
final String[] usernameAndPassword = getUsernameAndPassword();
System.out.println("received username: " + usernameAndPassword[0] + " and password " + usernameAndPassword[1]);
```

`getUsernameAndPassword()` is a method provided by the base class `UsernamePasswordLoginModule`.

Of course, the secured EJBs have to be annoteded with `@SecurityDomain("other")` (or via deployment-descriptor) to get my `CustomLoginModule` invoked.

Btw: I know that the security-domain `other` has some special meaning and should not be used for the application - this was just for testing... ;)

I was not very successful when trying to find an explanation for this. For me it seems that the login-modules are invoked in two steps: first when the `AppRealmLoopThrough` is used for the `ApplicationRealm` which is the security-realm for the `http-remoting-connector`. In this "step" the username and password are available.
The second "step" is the invocation of the `CustomLoginModule` when the container checks the EJB-permissions. In this phase by default there is no way to get the password (as tried initially). Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: Using the ClientLoginModule in this way would be exceptionally bad and could quite likely lead to credentials leaking to the wrong threads.

Comment: @DarranL Thanks for pointing this out! Can you confirm my assumption stated in the last paragraph? Is there a two-phase login procedure? Or even better: do you know where can I find useful documentation which describes the whole procedure and where which configuration and which module is used?

Is the problem you've written about a problem with the `ClientLoginModule` itself or am I completely on the wrong way with this approach? I.e. would it be better to use some other module like the `ConfiguredIdentityLoginModule` (which would work - at least in the single-thread case - too)?